# Why is " '2019-02-01'.to_date - Date.today" "442/1"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I did this:

```
'2019-02-01'.to_date - Date.today # => 442/1
```

Why is the return value not `442`?

Comment: It returns a rational because the difference doesn't have to be a whole number.

Answer (score 1):

Because `Date#-` returns a date or a rational. From the [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-2D):

> d - other → date or rational
>
> Returns the difference between the two dates if the other is a date object. If the other is a numeric value, returns a date object pointing other days before self. If the other is a fractional number, assumes its precision is at most nanosecond.

Answer (score 0):

It give the difference of days 
Try this

```
pry(main)> ('2019-02-01'.to_date - Date.today).to_i
=> 442
pry(main)> (Date.today + 2.days) - Date.today)
=> (2/1)
pry(main)> ((Date.today + 2.days) - Date.today)).to_i
=> 2
```

So, 442 is days difference.